# Django Pagination error at object of type 'HttpResponse' has no len()

Tags: python, django

I am developing ontop of my views the ability to have Django paginate my product list. Without pagination my code worked absolutely fine . This is the code I had before pagination

```
class JobListIndex2(TagMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'jobs/job_list.html'
    model = Job
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'job'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        return Job.objects.all()
```

I have then decided to integrate pagination and updated my code to this

```
class JobListIndex2(TagMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'jobs/job_list.html'
    model = Job
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'job'

    # def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     request = self.request
    #     return Job.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        queryset_list = Job.objects.all().order_by("-time_starting")
        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)  # Show 10 jobs per page

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        queryset = paginator.get_page(page)

        context = {
            'job': queryset,
            'title': 'Jobs'
        }
        return render(request, 'jobs/job_list.html', context)
```

The resulting error relates to object of type 'HttpResponse' has no len() which I am not sure where that has come from. My traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\views\generic\base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\views\generic\list.py", line 157, in get
    context = self.get_context_data()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\protectandserve\jobs\views.py", line 371, in get_context_data
    context = super(TagMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\views\generic\list.py", line 119, in get_context_data
    paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\views\generic\list.py", line 69, in paginate_queryset
    page = paginator.page(page_number)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\paginator.py", line 67, in page
    number = self.validate_number(number)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\paginator.py", line 45, in validate_number
    if number > self.num_pages:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\paginator.py", line 97, in num_pages
    if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django-2.1.1-py3.7.egg\django\core\paginator.py", line 92, in count
    return len(self.object_list)
TypeError: object of type 'HttpResponse' has no len()
[13/Nov/2018 07:42:46] "GET /jobs/jobs HTTP/1.1" 500 115769
```

Any tips please ?

Comment: There is no need to do this. ListView *already* has pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Method `get_queryset` must return QuerySet object. In your case you are trying to return an HttpResponse.

But in your case, you don't need to use Pagination class. The `ListView` does that automatically for you, if you specify `paginate_by` attribute.

If you want extra context in your template use

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(JobListIndex2, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = 'Jobs'
    return context
```